# How to select * but distinct pair of two columns in sql?

Tags: mysql

I want to see unique descritions for each collection_id. It'd be okay if names are duplicate but descriptions can not be allowed. I tried disctinct but it doesn't allow me to select all the columns.

| id | collection_id | description | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | ABC | X |
| 2 | 13 | ABD | Y |
| 3 | 12 | ABC | X |
| 4 | 13 | LMN | Y |
| 5 | 14 | OPQ | X |
| 6 | 14 | OPQ | Y |

To this

| id | collection_id | description | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | ABC | X |
| 2 | 13 | ABD | Y |
| 4 | 13 | LMN | Y |
| 5 | 14 | OPQ | X |

Comment: What do you mean by "for each collection_id"? You don't have `15` in the desired result.

Comment: It looks like you just want `GROUP BY description`

Comment: @Barmar Sorry just updated it

Comment: So you want `GROUP BY collection_id, description`.

Comment: @barmar, but can I select * in that case?

Comment: Yes, see the linked question for how to get all the columns of the row.

Comment: that question ignores the different values in other_columns

Comment: No it doesn't. It returns an entire row in each group.

Comment: I meant I want unique 'description' values for each group. No matter how many they are.

Comment: That's what it does. It prints one row for each group. You need to specify some criteria for which row in the group, like highest or lowest `id`.